# How to handle paths of JS and CSS in Golang Templates

Tags: go-templates

currently am working in a Golang Site, as frontend I am using the go templates. In order to separate the different parts of the sites I created this templates:

1. Head: containing the `<head>` tag, and some imports of css
2. Header: defining the navbar of the site, logo, etc. It's only HTML
3. Footer: defining the HTML of the footer of the site.
4. SomePage: defining the body tag, this template calls Head, Header and footer. This file can be for example the index, the login, etc.

I added the Javascript imports just after I nest the footer template, but still inside the body tag. As example, I added them like:

```
<script src="public/js/SomeJS.js"></script>
<link href="public/css/SomeCSS.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

In the routes of my project I have defined `public` to serve those static files, this is working pretty nice. Now, I have some routes of the project, lets say:

```
router.GET("/",controllers.Index)
router.GET("/login",controllers.Login)
```

With the first route, the libraries are being loaded pretty well. Then, with routes as the second, I am not able to load them because the browser tries to locate that files as:

```
http://myserver/login/public/css/someCSS.css  instead of
http://myserver/public/css/someCSS.css
```

In this case, I understand why it's adding the `login` to the URL. **So, my question is, how it's normally handled?**

By now I added the domain and folder to the imports, example:

```
<script src="MyDomain.com/public/js/SomeJS.js"></script>
```

But I really don't want to do it in this way, because anytime that the domain change I should be editing the code and it's not really pratical. Also, I don't want to add the imports of the libraries in every view that I create. I have some files (CSS and JS) that are common for all the project and I just want writte it once.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `/` in the being of the path, it is called `relative path` from `domain root`.

```
<script src="/public/js/SomeJS.js"></script>
<link href="/public/css/SomeCSS.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Without `/`, it is called as `relative path` from `current domain directory`. This is the behavior you have right now.

Output:

```
http://myserver/public/css/someCSS.css
http://myserver/public/js/SomeJS.js
```